# Automatically-learning filters in Google Mail

Tags: api, email, filter, gmail

setting up individual filters in Gmail requires a lot of clicks, especially if you have to do it all the time.
I am looking for a way to kill two birds with one stone and have **Gmail automatically create a filter when I select one or several messages and move them manually to a certain label.** So basically the plugin looks at what I do when moving emails to a label and copies that behaviour into a filter automatically.

I would be content if this were solely based on the sender of said mail(s) but of course it would be more perfect if the emails would be analyzed and - if ambiguous - I would be presented with an option (e.g. "Do you want to create the filter based on 'From' or on 'To'?")

**Example:**
Two emails in my inbox:

```
 o From: mail@amazon.xx     To: me@gmail.com   Subject: Your shopping order
 o From: service@amazon.xx  To: me@gmail.com   Subject: Your shopping return
```

I select both emails and click on **"Move to > *Shopping*"** (a label that I have previously created).
Now, Gmail creates a filter automatically on the basis of what I have just done, and I will never have to do it again. Ideally this happens intelligently, e.g. by looking into what the two emails have in common and providing me with a popup question:

```
AUTO-FILTER: 
>>Label with "Shopping" and archive<<
=====================================
Do you want to create the filter based on:
1) only mail from mail@amazon.xx and service@amazon.xx (the individual senders)
2) all mail from @amazon.xx (the sender domain)
3) all mail to me@gmail.com (the recipient)
4) all mail from 1 to 3 (the individual senders to the recipient)
5) all mail from 2 to 3 (the sender domain to the recipient)
6) all mail containing the subject "Your shopping"
_____________
Enter number:
```

1

```
OK   |   Cancel
```

Now my question: 
**Is anyone aware of a tool/plugin that can accomplish this (or something similar)?**

If not, how could I go about developing a tool for that myself (is there a Gmail filter API or way to write your own Labs plugin).

I am aware of the *Smart Label* Labs plugins but that really doesn't fit my needs as it is limited only to five preset categories which I wasn't able to even tweak (like trying to edit its filters, only gives an "invalid" error). Seems to have been done kind of half-hearted and not been updated in a long time (also creates a lot of false-positives in my inbox).

I appreciate any help, insight, pointers etc.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I know this will not help you, but for years I'm wondering too, why there is not much going on in classifying emails apart from ham and spam. I use the Opera email client for 15 years now. It has learning filters for as many categories as you like and e.g. perfectly sends Amazon commercials to the spam while my shopping confirmations from Amazon are stored in my "orders" folder. Of course, in the beginning it produces a lot of crap, but after some days, it works perfectly for at the moment 10 different filters.